# Set Locale in template

Tags: localization

I was wondering if there 's a quick way to just set a locale in your template for example:

```
{% set locale = 'en' %}
```

and then use that locale to get the correct content. I know that Craft automaticly uses the right locale based on the url, but I'm importing some templates from Craft with curl into another site and so the Craft template is unaware of the locale. That's why I would like to set it, if possible without the use of an extra plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t set the `craft.locale` from the template. You can set the locale for your Element Criteria though.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(14).locale('en').first() %}
```

Comment: hmm, that might work. Let me check that and see if I can fix it with this